# Segmentation fault when using strcpy?

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I'm trying to define a path at compile time by passing:

```
-DDCROOTDEF='"/path/to/stuff"'
```

on the compile line. I then try to get use this in the code like:

```
char * ptr_path;  
strcpy(ptr_path, DCROOTDEF);
strcat(ptr_path,"/MainCommons/CommonLib/fonts/Arial.ttf");
char *pftf=ptr_path;
gdImageStringFT(pimg,brect,iclr,pftf,pts,ang,ixp,iyp, (char *)cbuf);
```

Which gives me a segmentation fault. However, if I try to print the string first:

```
char * ptr_path;
strcpy(ptr_path, DCROOTDEF);
strcat(ptr_path,"/MainCommons/CommonLib/fonts/Arial.ttf");
char *pftf=ptr_path;
printf("%s\n",pftf);
gdImageStringFT(pimg,brect,iclr,pftf,pts,ang,ixp,iyp, (char *)cbuf);
```

It works just fine. What intricacy of char pointer's am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: How about adding a '\0' at the end of the string?

Comment: @karlphillip:  The `\0` is automatically included at the end of a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char * ptr_path;
strcpy(ptr_path, DCROOTDEF);
```

You never initialize `ptr_path`.

It doesn't work in the second code snippet, you are just getting unlucky and it *appears* to work.  You're still using an uninitialized pointer and trying to write to who knows where in memory.

You need to initialize `ptr_path` to point to an array of `char` that is at least `strlen(DCROOTDEF) + 1` in length.  You also need to check the length of `DCROOTDEF` before copying its contents into the array to be sure that it is not too long.  You can do so manually using `strlen` or  you can use a length-checked copy function like `strlcpy`.

Comment: strlcpy is non-standard,isn't it?

Comment: @Nyan:  `strlcpy` is nonstandard.  You can easily [find an implementation online](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/string/strlcpy.c?rev=1.11;content-type=text/plain).

Comment: If it appears to work, then it works. One possible outcome of undefined behaviour is the behaviour you were aiming for in the first place. Sadly.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `ptr_path` is not initialized to point at writable memory, which is why dereferencing it using `strcpy()` is crashing.

You need to call e.g. `malloc()` to get the space, first:

```
char * ptr_path = malloc(PATH_MAX);
```

Or something like that.

Comment: and you need to `free()` the memory when you've finished with it, too.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
char * ptr_path;
strcpy(ptr_path, DCROOTDEF);
strcat(ptr_path,"/MainCommons/CommonLib/fonts/Arial.ttf");
```

the pointer is not bound to a legally allocated block of memory, so your program runs into undefined behavior. You need to allocate a buffer first - for example by using `malloc()`. Be sure that the buffer is large enough to hold the resulting string together with the terminating null character.